# función asincrona retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo esta funcion que busca un registro en la **`DB`** y me lo muestra en la variable Follow. hasta aqui todo bien, cuando hago `console.log(follow);` envia el resultado.

Pero cuándo asigno la función a una variable en este caso asigno `following` y `followed` y hago el `console.log` de su resultado fuera me da `undefined`!!

```js
// Conseguir datos de un usuario
function getUser(req, res){
 var userId = req.params.id;

 User.findById(userId, (err, user) =>{
  if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la peticion'});

  if(!user) return res.status(404).send({message: 'El usuario no existe'});

  followThisUser(req.user.sub, userId).then((value) =>{

   user.password = undefined;
   return res.status(200).send({
    user,
    following: value.following,
    followed: value.followed
    
   });
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
 });
}
async function followThisUser(identity_user_id, user_id){

 var following = await Follow.findOne({"user" :identity_user_id, "followed" :user_id}).exec((err, follow) => {
  if(err) return handleError(err);

  return new Promise(resolve => {
   
   resolve(follow);

   });
 });

 var followed = await Follow.findOne({"user" :user_id, "followed" :identity_user_id}).exec((err, follow) => {
  if(err) return handleError(err);
  
  return new Promise(resolve => {
   
   resolve(follow);

   });
 });
 
 console.log(following);
 console.log(followed);
 
 return {
  following: following,
  followed: followed
 }

}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder,

Comment: lo he cambiado como dices pero aun asi me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Asi lo tengo y siguen UNDFINED

Comment: Hay alguna forma de mostrarte todo, un chat privado aqui, soy nuevo en Stack

Comment: suena a problema de CORS?

Comment: Jack he actualizado el codigo para que lo veas completo, he puesto la funcion de donde llamo a followThisUser. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Como haces las llamadas?? esta todo en el mismo servidor? las llamadas segun el navegador estan bien? no hay errores en la consola?

Comment: Que tal Gbianchi, soy nuevo en node y algunas cosas no las conozco, agradezco toda ayuda y explicaciones.

Comment: no tengo ningun error en la consola solo las variables no definidas,

Comment: he puesto una foto de lo que sucede en consola al realizar la llamada

Comment: incluso si me devuelve el objeto JSON de User pero no el Following y Followed

Comment: Hey lo he resuelto, pondré el código resuelto.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No Yeray. Si pones el codigo en la pregunta, las respuestas no tienen sentido y no se entiende si la pregunta esta resuelta o no. Voy a revertir tu edicion, y por favor pon el codigo con su explicacion como una respuesta

Comment: Oh ok tienes razon, soy nuevo Jeje

Comment: a proposito @YerayCorporations  borra los comentarios que no son necesarios!

Answer (score 4):

Cuando haces un `await` lo que sigue después es una llamada que retorna una promesa, en la forma:

```
let variable = await devuelvePromesa();
```

Si `devuelvePromesa` no devuelve una promesa, entonces no va a funcionar, al menos no como tú esperas.

En tu caso

```
Follow.findOne({"user" :identity_user_id, "followed" :user_id})
```

No devuelve una promesa. Más bien pareciera que genera una sentencia preparada (o algo de ese estilo). Esa sentencia la ejecutas encadenándola con

```
.exec((err, follow) => { ... }
```

Que tiene el footprint de la clásica función de node `(error, resultado) => { ... }`

Tienes tres opciones para resolver esto:

1.- Si la librería que estás usando soporta promesas (no dices qué librería es) puede que te aguante hacer algo como:

```
var following = await Follow
                      .findOne({"user" :identity_user_id, "followed" :user_id})
                      .then((follow) => { return follow; });
```

2.- Si la librería no aguanta promesas, puedes promisificarla usando bluebird [PromisifyAll](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) (Si estás trabajando con Mongoose, en realidad la opción 1 ya debiera haberte funcionado y no necesitas promisificar nada)

3.- El método más old school sería refactorizar tu código de manera que quedase:

```
async function findFollower(user, followed) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Follow.findOne({
            "user": user,
            "followed": followed
        }).exec((err, follow) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(follow);
        });
    });
}

async function followThisUser(identity_user_id, user_id) {
    var following = await findFollower(identity_user_id, user_id);
    var followed = await findFollower(user_id, identity_user_id):
}
```

con lo cual, en el fondo, estás envolviendo el callback en una promesa y no a la inversa.

Recuerda envolver tus awaits en bloques try/catch

Comment: creo que va mas alla de eso , [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)  cambia un poco el comportamiento igual la ultima parte de como se usa creo que debe funcionar

Comment: Bueno, la tercera manera seguro que funciona, pero por lo que dice la documentación, usar `.then` también funcionaría. (En todo caso, salvo por tu comentario, no había visto que el OP estaba usando mongoose, yo uso el driver nativo de MongoDB con una sintaxis casi igual)

Comment: si, solo agrega la unica forma para no ensuciar tu respuesta

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda lo he resuelto usando Then

Comment: Esa es la primera opción que te puse

Answer (score 2):

Lo he resuelto usando then como dice la documentacion de [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), el problema no estaba en la llamada si no en la misma función **async**

de esta manera me ha funcionado cambiando **.exec()** por **.then()**.

```js
async function followThisUser(identity_user_id, user_id){

 var following = await Follow.findOne({"user" :identity_user_id, "followed" :user_id}).then((follow) => {

  return follow });

 var followed = await Follow.findOne({"user" :user_id, "followed" :identity_user_id}).then((follow) => {

  return follow });
 
 console.log(following);
 console.log(followed);
 
 return {

  following: following,
  followed: followed
 }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar esta respuesta dentro de 24 hs!

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que estas usando mongoose

```
// Conseguir datos de un usuario
function getUser(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;
    User.findById(userId, (err, user) =>{
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la peticion'});

        if(!user) return res.status(404).send({message: 'El usuario no existe'});

        followThisUser(req.user.sub, userId).then((value) =>{

            user.password = undefined;
            return res.status(200).send({
                user,
                following: value.following,
                followed: value.followed

            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
}
async function followThisUser(identity_user_id, user_id){

    var following = await Follow.findOne({"user" :identity_user_id, "followed" :user_id}).exec();
    var followed = await Follow.findOne({"user" :user_id, "followed" :identity_user_id}).exec();

    console.log(following);
    console.log(followed);

    return {
        following: following,
        followed: followed
    }

}
```

Comment: Lo he resuelto de otra manera, muchas gracias actualizare el código por si tienen alguna opinión.

Comment: @YerayCorporations responde la pregunta  con lo elemental la idea es que otros usuarios no tengan tu problemas